# nodejs express production mode clear cache programmatically

Tags: node.js, express

I need to be able to programmatically clear the cache of a nodejs / express / jade site without restarting the engine.

I have tried the following but it appears to do nothing and node/express continues to happily serve up all of it's cached pages.

```
delete (app.cache);
```

How can I force express / nodejs to clear it's cache and reload it's cached pages (jade views).

Comment: how about using pm (https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/pm.html) to `soft-restar`t the app?

Comment: Thanks, I am already using pm2 but this just restarts the engine which I need to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Templates are cached in a jade.cache object.
Try something like this

```
//jade = require('jade');
for (let template in jade.cache) {
  delete jade.cache[template];
}
```